# How do I represent exact coordinates if the Canvas size and each pixel are different sizes?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have configured `Canvas` like this to represent some kind of graph with `Canvas` tag.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The `width` and `height` of `Canvas` are `650`, `300`.

Also, I used transform to start the coordinate position with `(0, 0)` from the bottom left.

```
const canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width  = 650;
canvas.height = 300;

let maxXCoord = 250;

let xCoordRate = canvas.width / maxXCoord;

context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)';

context.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 650, 0);

// Draw canvas grid line for x
for(let x = 25 * xCoordRate; x < canvas.width; x += 25 * xCoordRate) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.setLineDash([2, 4]);
  context.moveTo(x, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  context.stroke();
};

// Draw canvas grid line for y
for(let y = 50; y < canvas.height; y += 50) {
  if(y === 150) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.setLineDash([]);
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width - 1, y);
        context.stroke();
  } else {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.setLineDash([2, 4]);
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
        context.stroke();
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Through the code above, the actual size of the `Canvas` is `650` and `300`, but when I draw a line for some coordinate value, I want to change the coordinate value as if it were up to `250` and `60`.

If the following coordinate values are received, how should the coordinates converted?

```
point = [
   {
     x : 0.00000,
     y : 0.00000
   },
   {
     x : 303.655197,
     y : 101.073993
   },
   {  
     x : 306.341,
     y : 130.2344
   },
   {
     x : 101.3495,
     y : 91.96
   }
   ...
]
```

If the following code is executed, the result is strange as shown below.

```
for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.setLineDash([]);
        context.strokeStyle = 'green';

        context.moveTo(array[index].point[0].x, array[index].point[0].y);

        for(let _index = 0; _index < array[index].point.length; _index++) {

            context.lineTo(array[index].point[_index].x * coordRate, array[index].point[_index].y * coordRate + (canvas.height / 2));
        }

        context.stroke();
 }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: @Gass To put it a little more simply, the actual size of the canvas is `650`, `300`, but when drawing lines using coordinates, I want to draw with `250`, `60` as the standard. In other words, it seems to be necessary to convert the coordinates to be drawn by calculating the ratio of the actual `canvas` to the maximum coordinates set. But I don't know exactly how to do this.

Comment: I think I get it now. Can you add a snippet of your full code?

Comment: @Gass The code related to the problem is all above. Shall we add the `Point` array value to get a more precise understanding?

Comment: Why not use global variables to declare these other dimensions? `var heightTwo = 60, widthTwo = 250;`  ? and then work with them to draw?

Comment: @Gass I hadn't even thought of using another dimension of global variables. If the width of `Canvas` is `650` and you want to express up to `250` in the real coordinate system, I thought that `650 / 250` would be sufficient.

Comment: `650 / 250` ? What is this meant to be ? I'm having problems trying to understand..

Comment: @Gass I'm drawing a graph with `Canvas`. `650` means the actual `Canvas width`, and `250` means the maximum value on the `X-axis` of the graph.

Comment: I understand all of that, but why are you dividing those two values?

Comment: @Gass The reason we separated the values is that there is a style code for the `Canvas` element, and the maximum value for each `axis` used for that `canvas` graph is different.

Comment: But in the sample data you provide you have x values going over 250. Does that mean it will simply appear to be off the graph?

Comment: @MichaelBeeson Yes. If it exceeds the maximum value, I thought of a form that crosses the `X` axis.

Answer (score 0):

I get a feeling that you are over complicating things with the transform.
If all you need is to start the coordinate position with (0, 0) from the bottom left you can do that with a simple subtraction of the height.

Here is an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 160;

point = [
   { x: 0,   y: 0 },
   { x: 40,  y: 101 },
   { x: 80,  y: 130 },
   { x: 120, y: 91 }
]

//(0, 0) from the bottom left
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.moveTo(point[0].x, canvas.height - point[0].y);
for (let index = 0; index < point.length; index++) {
    context.lineTo(point[index].x, canvas.height - point[index].y)
}
context.stroke();

//(0, 0) from the top left 
context.beginPath()
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.moveTo(point[0].x, point[0].y);
for (let index = 0; index < point.length; index++) {
    context.lineTo(point[index].x, point[index].y)
}
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: It was a good example. I think it can be solved easily like this. However, I'm curious how to properly scale the `X` axis value to the actual `canvas width`.